# Settings hierarchy in .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, configuration, app-config

I would like to have a mixture of .net core and .net framework applications share common app.configs.

For instance :

```
app.settings
\WebAppOne\app.settings
\WebAppOne\SubAppOneA\app.settings
\WebAppTwo\app.settings
```

I would like to be able to publish these apps to IIS, and in WebAppOne\SubAppOneA be able to pull a setting from the root app.Settings as well as \WebAppOne\app.settings

I have tried building the apps just as in, and tried accessing the settings via ConfigurationManager, hoping it would just work out of the box :

```
this.LocalConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myDb"].ConnectionString;
this.ChildConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["childDb"].ConnectionString;
```

But clearly, this did not work as I hoped. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to use the "old" .config (xml) or the "new" .json configuration?

Comment: @MatteoUmili, for now, xml, but going forward, JSON.

Comment: I think that with the classic xml you can't achieve cleanly what you want, but using the json configuration it is quite easily feasible

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that does not seem to be supported.

Only thing i can think of is to instead save the common settings in `common.settings` and create a custom build process to copy that file to the root of the other projects. Also see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-application-settings-dotnet?view=vs-2019#use-customized-settings-files).

I'm working on enterprise software and instead of all that we use a simple xml file for this. We then have a class that mirrors this file in code. We define our values here. At startup the file gets written to MyApp/bin/debug/settings and the application moves most settings to the database. When a user alters the file the file is checked against the database again.

Answer (score 0):

Your title indicates that you want to [`Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration/) for your configuration. This can be used in full framework projects too and also [supports XML](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Xml/).

For the hierarchical scheme that you want to use you will have to implement that yourself: How to search for XML files and how they should be layered.

When you configure your system using .NET Core configuration you cannot use `ConfigurationManager`. Instead you will have to use `IConfiguration`. You can read values directly using `IConfiguration` but I recommend using the [options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options) or at least bind configuration to models using [`ConfigurationBinder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbinder).

Here's a minimal example on how to use `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` outside .NET Core and the hosting models it provides:

For starters here is a configuration file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<Settings>
  <ConnectionStrings>
    <MyDb>foo</MyDb>
    <ChildDb>bar</ChildDb>
  </ConnectionStrings>
</Settings>
```

An options class to bind to:

```
class ConnectionStringOptions
{
    public string MyDb { get; set; }
    public string ChildDb { get; set; }
}
```

The following will create the configuration and bind it to the options. The second part where the service provider is used to get the options is normally automatically done using dependency injection but that is not a requirement.

```
var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    // TODO: Add more XML files based on the search and layering rules.
    .AddXmlFile("appSettings.xml");
var configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();

var services = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddOptions()
    .Configure<ConnectionStringOptions>(configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));
var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

var options = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<ConnectionStringOptions>>();
var connectionStringOptions = options.Value;
```

For this to compile you need the following NuGet packages:

- `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Xml`
- `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`
- `Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions`